# vue test utils SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am getting error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` in index file where I am trying to load components via lazy load approach.

```
const templates = () => import('@/pages/templates');
```

It works fine if used the syntax:

```
import templates from '@/pages/templates';
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic `import` statements are a Webpack feature*, so when you compile code with Jest, dynamic `import` will  be undefined. You can solve this by using [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) in your babel config for tests:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
        "react",
        "stage-0"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "dynamic-import-node"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Although it conforms to a [TC39 spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)